# I'm not getting the expected results from this if statement and echo prompt using exit-codes

Tags: linux, bash

So I'm trying to have a script that gives different responses/echo-prompts depending on what the last exit-code is. This, imo, should work as this script runs every minute suing crontab and therefore it doesn't affect the last exit code. However, I'm not getting any promts no matter what the exit value is.

I've tried simply displaying the value of RESULT(exit-code) using echo, which used to work but now seemingly does not display when using crontab. I've made sure the script runs by using the 'else' statement and 'logger -s', however that sends a log whether the actual exit-code is equal to 0 or not, and it should only send it if the value is actually equal to 0. I've tried different operators etc. but nothing seems to be able to actually send an 'echo' prompt..

```
#!/bin/bash

RESULT=$(echo "$?")


        if [ $RESULT -gt 0 ]
        then
                echo "Value is greater than 0"
        else [ $RESULT -eq 0 ]

                echo "Value is equal to 0"
fi
```

This is driving me crazy as I feel it shouldn't be that difficult, but apparently it is haha. Expected result is that it should give out an echo promt when the exit-code of the last entered command is '0', and give out a different value when the exit-code is greater than '0' (the command failed), but instead nothing is happening unless I send it to the log in which case it pretty much always ends up in there.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Why comment and not answer?

Comment: @ceving I ... can't think of a good reason. So I converted my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `$(... )` is a subshell. There is no previous status before the `echo`.

So just use

```
RESULT=$?
...
```

Comment: The subshell isn't actually a problem here, since the subshell inherits `$?`. The lack of a previous command *is* a problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three problems here:

1. `$?` gets the exit status of the last command run by *that particular shell*; since this is at the beginning of a script there is no last command, so it defaults to "0".
2. Output from cron jobs doesn't go to a terminal, it basically gets ignored.
3. `else [ $RESULT -eq 0 ]` doesn't do anything useful, since the `else` keyword doesn't take a condition. (Well, technically, it does execute the test as a regular command, but the result is ignored.)

And a couple of bonus recommendations:

4. Don't use `$(echo ...)` or `echo $(...)` -- the `$( )` and `echo` mostly cancel each other.
5. Use lower- or mixed-case variable names (e.g. `result` instead of `RESULT`). There are a bunch of all-caps names with special meanings, and if you accidentally use one of them for something else it can cause problems. Lower- and mixed-case names avoid this risk.

Comment: Ok, thank you! How do you suggest I get a script to run in intervals without using crontab?

Comment: @simedr If you want access to the exit status of the last command run by a particular shell, you need to be running *in that shell*. That means no scripts (scripts run in their own shells), and there's no standard way to do periodic things within a running shell. Depending on the actual goal, you might be able to do something with [`trap`](https://ss64.com/bash/trap.html) or the [`PROMPT_COMMAND' variable](https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-prompt.html).

Answer (score 0):

Youre trying to assign the last status of a command to `RESULT` using `$?` which will return 1 or 0. But I dont see any command before the assignment or even setting the initial value of `RESULT` so your if statement will never achieve the desired result.